# obout combobox setValue()

Tags: asp.net, combobox, obout

I am using an obout combobox to display color swatches for a product catalog and it's very cool except for one thing.

When on the server, I set the .Value property explicity (for a reset) it IS setting on the serverside, but not in the client.

For example, I add all my color swatches from Linq, but then add a default setting of "Color..." with a value of "".  But on first display the combobox shows as empty (the text part).  When I click the down arrow, then everything is correct.

I've tried setting the index, the value, the text and none work.

I have also added a registerclientscript to try and force this on the client side and while the script is running (test with an alert), the box is not getting set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you cannot set a value to "", you must set it to " ".  Then it will work. :)